# How to call parameterized controller in apex command button in visualforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I have a apex class of the following type

```
public standardcontroller(){

List<account> accountList = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 20];
ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(accountList);
List<Account> selected=ssc.getSelected();
}


public PageReference save(List<Account> selected){
 if(code logic)
}
```

The visual force page contains a command button

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton"/>
```

How to pass the parameter List selected when calling save method from vf page

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the Id of that record (In case of the detail button)

```
Id recordId = standardController.getId();
Account record = (Account) standardController.getRecord();
PageReference pdfPage = new PageReference('/apex/YOURVFPAGENAME');
pdfPage.getParameters().put('id',recorded);
```

Now you have the Id of that record, now you can perform any action in the controller base on that ID.